# Call Fragment method from PopupMenu

Tags: android, android-activity, methods, fragment, call

so I'm trying to call a method from my fragment class in activity class. In my activity I have bottom navigation view (and PopupMenu in it) from which I'm trying to call method from fragment.

This is my activity with the solution I've found googling, but it doesn't work for me:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MapFragment map = new MapFragment();
    TextView textView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.text_main)).setText(MainActivity.selectedButton);

        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        selectedFragment = new MapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();


        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_map);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_map:
                            selectedFragment = new MapFragment();
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_sensors:
                            selectedFragment = new SensorsFragment();
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_apps:
                            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MenuActivity.this, findViewById(R.id.nav_apps));
                            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                            inflater.inflate(R.menu.bottom_nav_menu, popup.getMenu());
                            popup.show();
                            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                                        case R.id.nav_floor:
                                            map.test();
                                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Floor",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            break;
                                        case R.id.nav_room:
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Room",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            break;
                                        case R.id.nav_search:
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Search",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            break;

                    }

                    return true;
                }

            };
}
```

And my fragment (I have a couple other methods for Maps in this class, but this is the one I'm testing this with):

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment{

View mView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

    public void test(){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Also, XML files:

activity_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav_map"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_color"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
    />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/location_button"
        android:text="LOC"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

To summarize it, I'm trying to call method test() when I selected first option in Popup menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `test` on an instance of a fragment that is never added to the fragment manager.

```
// You initialize this field
MapFragment map = new MapFragment();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Then you initialize a new MapFragment you add to the fragment manager
    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
    selectedFragment = new MapFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
}

...
// Then you call `test` on the instance that's not attached to anything
map.test();
```

The solution is to use ONE fragment and refer to that. And you also want to be careful to handle saving and restoring the state of the fragment correctly.

```
MapFragment map; // Declare but don't initialize here

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Initialize fragment instead of creating a new one if there is no state already
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        map = new MapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, map).commit();
    }
    else {
        // If there is state, the fragment will be restored by the system, so just
        // get a reference to it
        map = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_containter)
    }
}

...
// Now calling test on the correctly attached fragment should work
map.test();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great, glad it helped you. If this answers your question, it's useful for me and other to mark the answer as "accepted".